# How to print special value of dynamic array?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I've got an array of arrays they have a different value.

i want to print `[name]` field values of array ...

every time i use foreach my result not good...!

```
Array
(
    [und] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [tid] => 5683
                    [taxonomy_term] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [tid] => 5683
                            [name] => deded


                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [tid] => 15143
                    [taxonomy_term] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [tid] => 15143
                            [name] => dedeededswswsw


                        )

                )

        )

)
```

my code :

```
$array= ($array['und']);
foreach($array as $newarray){
    print_r ($newarray);
}
```

thanks for your helps

Comment: "_my result not good_" meaning what exactly? Getting the `tid` field? Where do you access the `name` field in your code?

Comment: @kerbholz yes return `[tid]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will notice that the output has more levels before you get to the `name` field.  If you follow the structure

```
Array
(
    [tid] => 5683
    [taxonomy_term] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 5683
            [name] => deded
        )

)
```

you would need to output...

```
foreach($array as $newarray){
    echo $newarray['taxonomy_term']->name.PHP_EOL;
}
```